# Assign value to char in array

Tags: c

I'm trying to brush up on my C/C++ and I seem to have forgotten how to properly manipulate char arrays.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* str)
{
    int numChar = strlen(str);
    char *reversed = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (numChar + 1));

    int i = numChar;
    int j = 0;
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        reversed[j] = str[i];
        j++;
        i--;
        printf("%c", reversed[j]);
    }

    printf("%s", reversed);
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    strcpy(str, "apple\0");
    reverse(str);
    return 0;   
}
```

I'm very certain I'm not doing what I intend to with `reversed[j] = str[i]` as `reversed` comes out empty. What's the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From first glance, In main(), memory has to be allocated to character pointer str before referencing it in strcpy

```
int main()
{
    char* str = malloc(6)  or use char str[6];
    // or char *str = "apple"; is sufficient, strcpy is not required in this case 
    strcpy(str, "apple\0");
    reverse(str);
    return 0;   
}
```

Another one :
In reverse() function, you will have to increment **j** after printing

```
while(i >= 0)
{
    reversed[j] = str[i];
    printf("%c", reversed[j]);
    j++;         //Moved here
    i--;
}
reversed[j] = '\0'          //Null termination

printf("\n %s", reversed);
```

or only the below two statements would be sufficient enough to post increment j and decrement i

```
reversed[j] = str[i--];
printf("%c", reversed[j++]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you start with i being the strlen of the input string (e.g. `HAHA` -> 4), you start copying at haha[4], which is the null byte at the end of the string.  IOW you just null terminated your output right at the start.  Try setting i to `numChar - 1`.

(After fixing the problem Santosh A mentioned)

And then, make sure you null terminate the result!